# hidden_field_tag not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

As per code below text_area generates `<input name='user_comment[text]../>`. However hidden_field_tag fails with an error because it requires different parameters. What would be the most elegant way to generate a hidden tag with `name="user_comment[forum_id]" value=".."`

```
<% @forums.each do |forum| %>
    .....
    <%=form_tag(user_comments_path, method: "post", remote: true) do %>
      <%= text_area(:user_comment, :text) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:user_comment, :forum_id, forum.id) %>
      <%= submit_tag("Add Comment") %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature of [hidden_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) is this:

> hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})

So this should work:

```
hidden_field_tag("user_comment[forum_id]", forum.id)
```